# Comp and e/a explanation

Tags: power-supply

Can anyone explain me E/A and comp in this IC?
[image]

Comment: E/A = error amplifier. Comp = comparator input.

Comment: Include a link to the datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/uc2845.pdf

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I see the datasheet but i cant understand it. can you explain me ?

Comment: If you do a search on the terms PWM error amplifier and PWM comp, what turns up?

Comment: *I see the datasheet but i cant understand it. can you explain me ?* I can, do you have a couple of days? My normal rate is € 150/hr. But seriously, if you can't understand the datasheet, why are you looking at the internals of this IC? You can just use the IC as is shown in application diagrams without understanding how the IC works.

Comment: @winny Comp here is not Comparator, but Compensation; to drive a feedback network to control the system's frequency response.

Comment: @user_1818839 Interesting! On the outside it's connected to the compensation network but on the inside it's connected to the PWM comparator. I've heard both.